# Minimal example of C++ class using Eigen objects exposed to R via Rcpp not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to reproduce the example given [here](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/exposing-a-cpp-student-class-with-rcpp/#2-setup-c-files), which is a class with methods written in `C++` and which contains methods that are exposed to R via `Rcpp`. My modification is to use classes that use `Eigen`.

My aim is to extend this example so that I can use `Eigen` by adding a method that provides the 2x2 Identity matrix.

There are currently two ways to do that, one (I suppose) is to add Eigen's headers as I normally would in a C++ programme while the other is to use `#include <RcppEigen.h>` and the tag `//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]`

I tried to extend the code with the following lines in `glue.cpp`

```
// Expose (some of) the MatrixAttempt class
RCPP_MODULE(MatrixAttempt){
  class_<MatrixAttempt>("MatrixAttempt")
  .method("GetIdentity",&MatrixAttempt::GetIdentity);
}
```

with the sole method

```
  Eigen::MatrixXd GetIdentity();
```

In that same header file, I added `#include <Eigen/Core>` in one attempt and

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// via the depends attribute we tell Rcpp to create hooks for
// RcppEigen so that the build process will know what to do
//
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
```

in another. When I compile the project with `devtools::load_all()` or simply click source on the `glue.cpp` file, I see my class. Constructing it with `myattempt <- new(MatrixAttempt)` works, too. When I call the method with `myattempt$GetIdentity()` my R sessions aborts with a fatal error.

The full reproducible example is:

```
  //  MatrixAttempt.hpp

#ifndef MatrixAttempt_hpp
#define MatrixAttempt_hpp



#include <RcppEigen.h>

// via the depends attribute we tell Rcpp to create hooks for
// RcppEigen so that the build process will know what to do
//
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

class MatrixAttempt
{
public:
  
  // Constructor
  MatrixAttempt();
  
  // Methods
  Eigen::MatrixXd GetIdentity();
  
};

#endif /* MatrixAttempt */
```

with implementation `MatrixAttempt.cpp`

```
#include "MatrixAttempt.hpp"


// Constructor
MatrixAttempt::MatrixAttempt() {}



Eigen::MatrixXd MatrixAttempt::GetIdentity(){
  return(Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(2,2));
}
```

and `glue.cpp`

```
// glue.cpp
// To use c++11, first run: Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")  ...or use a Makevars file

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "MatrixAttempt.hpp"
using namespace Rcpp;





// Expose (some of) the MatrixAttempt class
RCPP_MODULE(MatrixAttempt){
  class_<MatrixAttempt>("MatrixAttempt")
  .method("GetIdentity",&MatrixAttempt::GetIdentity);
}
```

### Update

I created a minimal repo [here](https://github.com/jsimons8/eigenclasses/). To reproduce the error, run `Rcpp::sourceCpp('src/glue.cpp')` in the R terminal and run `myinstance<-new(matrixAttempt)` and execute `myinstance$GetIdentity()`. Using `devtools::load_all()` or `pkgbuild::compile_dll()` does not show any classes in my R session.

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what you are doing and what is going without a _concrete_ yet _minimal_ verifiable and complete example.  Can you maybe setup a minimal repo?

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel , yes shall do that shortly. Thank you!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel https://github.com/jsimons8/eigenclasses contains a minimal repo.

Comment: https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-modules-student <- is from 2 years ago. Are those techniques still current?

Comment: Thanks for the repo, see my answer.  Re r-pkg-examples, maybe ask the repo owner/author.  (And I didn't downvote.)

Comment: In general you should not use `sourceCpp()` with Rcpp Modules.  Modules need some initialization code which is what you get from a package. Lots of existing examples.

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling. Here is what fixed it though: I forgot to add a line in the RCPP_MODULE:   .constructor() was missing, which was very silly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly making this too complicated?  Converters do exist, and have for a long time.  E.g.

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("Eigen::MatrixXd foo() {        \
         return Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(2,2); }", \
                    depends="RcppEigen")
> foo()
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
>
```

works as is, and has for a long time. (Line breaks added for display.) Same in packages, and *many* existing examples on CRAN.

Comment: Thank you! However, my function was just a contrived example and I need to do more than just return an identity matrix. I want to write oo c++ code I want to port to R/Rcpp thet benefits from using instances of a class rather than a simple function. Is there no MWE for a class exposed to R that uses Eigen objects, a bit like the Kalman example in your book, Ch. 12?

Comment: Have you looked at _e.g._ Doug's old but still fantastic class for [`fastLm` in Eigen](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/src/fastLm.cpp)?  It cleanly separates out all the gymnastics to 'standard' C++ and uses one function (with autogenerated glue) to report the result back to R.  That is a pretty simple and universal design.  Rcpp Modules is a _simple_ mechanism to do something with classes but it cannot be all things to all people all the time.

Comment: thank you for suggesting fastLm, it's exactly what I had in mind; it should probably be promoted on the Rcpp gallery. Now, the 'exposing' method differs in that it only exposes the one function with the export tag. Constructing objects in R using the Modules mechanism that have Eigen objects is then not fully supported?

Comment: I'd be up for writing something like that class up for the Gallery -- I also had forgotten about it.  So while you are in "that space", do you want to draft something as a start?

Comment: Yes, I'd be happy to draft something. My ultimate purpose is to create a class that constructs a functor which represents a likelihood. Construction involves adding a data set and some parameters so that only the functor can be plugged into DEOptim or optim. Because the parameters vary a bit from problem to problem, construction should take place in R hence my desire to use Modules. I shall experiment with the code a bit and report back.

Comment: Sounds promising!  (Small aside: Have your seen RcppDE where I pass an Rcpp-compiled function down to compiled code for optimization?  Maximum likelhood estimation and repeated evaluation of a (then compiled) function is a use case for that.)  We could possibly even contrast a Modules approach with a plain one.

Comment: First of all, I got it to work using Modules, which I will push to the minimal repo. In other words, Modules play nice with Eigen/RcppEigen which is good news. Basically, something like the fastLM example could be implemented with more granularity in R, where R users can then control construction of objects themselves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235675/discussion-between-hirek-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).